# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'add</int:product_id/>' uses paramet er name 'product_id/'

Tags: python, django

Views.py

```
def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart


def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            _cart_id=_cart_id(request)
        )
        cart.save(),
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            quantity=1,
            cart=cart
        )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

urls.py

```
path('add</int:product_id/>', views.add_cart,name='add_cart'),
```

Comment: Please add the *full* traceback to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The path expression is incorrect. Slashes are written *outside* of the path converter, so:

```
#        ↓ slashes        ↓ slashes
path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart,name='add_cart'),
```